# Using a servlet in Liferay

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, liferay

I have to get an image from an url finished in /jcaptcha.jpg

I've defined in the web.xml file the following nodes:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jcaptcha</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.domain.portales.jcaptcha.servlet.ImageCaptchaServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jcaptcha</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/jcaptcha.jpg</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In my jsp, I try to get the image, and I get it, but the code of doGet method of my servlet doesn´t execute. However, if I get the image using the following code

```
<p><img id="imgrecarga" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/jcaptcha.jpg"/></p>
```

that produces the value

```
/WCAC_FormularioContacto-portlet/jcaptcha.jpg
```

I obtain the image rigth and enter to the doGet() method.

It's strange because on that path doesn't exist the .jpg file.

I have to obtain the image by the first way entering on the doGet method, anyone knows what is happening? Have I to configure something on Liferay?

Comment: Where is the image stored?  Is it in the document library or are you trying to serve up an image stored somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the problem was because I was using a bad domain. For my local tests I've to access with an url starting by localhost:8080...